# How to keep track of if data is outdated

Tags: xbee, array

I have a large set of data and it is refreshed every 30 seconds or so. However, not all data is refreshed every time. It is possible that no new data for a particular calculation isn't received for even a few hours. For this reason I need to track what data is possibly outdated, but hasn't been updated (maybe due to technical malfunctions or a sensor is down). I was thinking about creating an additional (large) 2d array to do this, and increment some sort of counter. This way if a particular spot is at `1000` this means it is old. When new data is received it can be reset to `0`. However, this seems like a slow, ineffective way to do this. How could I keep track of data more efficiently?

Comment: It depends what form the data takes.

Comment: Also what you are using the data for.

Comment: @Majenko the data is all integers stored in arrays. It is just being stored and displayed on a webpage. So it'd be great to have some indication of what data on the page is old

Comment: What range are the values?

Comment: @Majenko -1 (indicating no data available) to 1000

Comment: You could add a timestamp for each value (or set of values). It would hold the time when the value(s) was latest updated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you have three possible states for your values:

1. No valid data (-1, or 0xFFFF in 16-bit 2's complement)
2. Valid data (0 to 1000, or 0x0000 to 0x03EB in 16-bit)
3. Valid but "old" data.

If you first check for invalid data before thinking about "old" data (invalid data is never considered "old") then you just have two states:

1. Valid data (0 to 1000, or 0x0000 to 0x03EB in 16-bit)
2. Valid but "old" data.

As you can see the highest 6 bits of the stored value aren't used at all except for storing -1 for invalid data (hence checking for that first). So you could utilize those 6 bits to store all sorts of things. In 6 bits you can store the values 0 to 63. That could be the number of seconds since the last time you got some data.

By masking and shifting you can separate out the two values:

```
val = data[x] & 0x3FF;
sec = data[x] >> 10;
```

Every second add one to the seconds count of each and every data entry that is less than (say) 60.

```
val = data[x] & 0x3FF;
sec = data[x] >> 10;
if (sec < 60) sec++;
data[x] = val | (sec << 10);
```

Now each entry in your array knows how old it is (up to 1 minute), and if it's older than a certain threshold (30 seconds? 45 seconds? you choose) then you consider it "old" and display it as such.

You can make it easier to program by using a union/struct combination:

```
typedef union {
    int16_t rawval;
    struct {
        unsigned value:10;
        unsigned seconds:6;
    } __attribute__((packed));
} data_t __attribute__((packed));
```

If your data array is now made up of that type instead of integers:

```
data_t data[500];
```

you can now access:

- data[x].rawval as the raw 16 bit signed value (to look for -1).
- data[x].value as the unsigned 10 bit value from 0 to 1000.
- data[x].seconds as the unsigned 6 bit value from 0 to 63.

Updating the seconds then becomes as simple as:

```
if (data[x].seconds < 60) data[x].seconds++;
```

When you store a new value using

```
data[x].rawval = sensor.getValue();
```

the seconds is automatically overwritten with 0 which resets the count for you.

And both methods give you data ageing without using a single byte more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than frequently updating a time flag for each data item, you can store a “generation number” for each item.  Maintain a “current generation number” `currentGen` and at intervals add one to it.  If the interval at which you increment `currentGen` is 20 seconds and you store 16-bit generation numbers, rollover will occur about every 15 days.  [20*2¹⁶/3600/24 = 15.17 days.]

For example, suppose your data structure has fields for item.value and item.gen.  Whenever you store a new value into item.value, copy `currentGen` into item.gen.  Later, to tell the age of an item, use `unsigned int` arithmetic to subtract item.gen from `currentGen`.  For example, if  `currentGen` is 23453, an element with item.gen = 17487 is about 33 hours old.

Note, if item age ever exceeds 15.17 days, it will wrap around to zero.  It that's a concern, either use a larger datatype for item.gen, or update `currentGen` less frequently, for example every two minutes for a 90-day wraparound or every 8 minutes for a 364-day wraparound time.